# Teams Search Showing Onpremisesamaccountnam

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are facing strange issue. Suddenly Teams search showing Onpremisesamaccountname under User name if we search users. It was 1stname.lastname before. Can anyone help me to check where i can change this back ?

hided the Onpremisesamaccountname with yellow mark in below image
[Teams Screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFgR8.jpg)

Comment: where you are searching the user? Could you please share more info and repro steps?

Comment: We are searching from the teams search bar in the top and its suddenly started behaving like that. No changes made

Comment: please reach out to the [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.